# How to properly comment functions in Python

Tags: python, comments

I would like advice on how I should structure my comments for functions. Is the description I currently have too in-depth?

The following code is for an algorithm that solves the n-queens problem.

```
def hill_climbing(initial_board):
    """
    While the current Board object has lower heuristic value successors, neighbour is randomly assigned to one.
    If the current Board's heuristic value is less than or equal to its neighbour's, the current Board object is
    returned. Else, the current variable is assigned the neighbour Board object and the while loop continues until
    either the current Board has no better successors, or current's h value is less than or equal to all of its
    successors.

    :param initial_board: A Board object with a randomly generated state, and successor_type of "best".
                          i.e. a start state
    :return: A Board object that has no further successors. i.e. a goal state (Local/Global Minimum)
    """
    current = initial_board
    while current.has_successors():
        neighbour = Board(current.get_random_successor(), "best")
        if neighbour.value() >= current.value():
            return current
        current = neighbour
    return current
```

Comment: If your code requires horizontal scroll, you're doing it wrong. Keep them short and sweet.

Comment: Did you read PEPs https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/?

Comment: I think if you really need it very detail, just do it, you just need care about pep257

Comment: Technically, this is a docstring rather than a comment, but agreed with above 3 suggestions.

Comment: Since it's for an assignment, I was thinking about if I should go in-depth on the detail. However by taking everyone's advice into consideration, would something like this be better for the main paragraph: Performs a hill climbing search on initial_board and returns a Board representing the goal state (local/global minimum).

Comment: Instead of talking about the while loops and comparisons that can be seen in the code?

Comment: A function docstring should concisely describe the function's purpose. It might describe the parameters and results if their names are not enough descriptive choice, or for complete documentation purposes. Unless the function uses some elaborated and unusual algorithm, don't see a reason to describe it, and specially not in a manner that replicates code via some natural language pseudo-code. Also, if it is complex enough to deserve a long explanation, maybe it should be further divided into smaller simpler functions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alexey's advice, I followed the PEPs and they provided great guidelines for commenting.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

My resulting comment:

```
def hill_climbing(initial_board):
""" Hill Climbing Algorithm.

Performs a hill climbing search on initial_board and returns a Board
object representing a goal state (local/global minimum).

Attributes:
    current: A Board object
    neighbour: A Board object that is a successor of current

:param initial_board: A Board object with a randomly generated state, and successor_type of "best".
                      i.e. a start state
:return: A Board object that has no further successors. i.e. a goal state (Local/Global Minimum)
"""

current = initial_board
while current.has_successors():
    neighbour = Board(current.get_random_successor(), "best")
    if neighbour.value() >= current.value():
        return current
    current = neighbour
return current
```